# need help to get float value of css 'font-size'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help to get float value of css 'font-size'. In firefox it works perfect.
I have trouble in Chrome, Safari, IE...
I try to get this css value but result-less, it converts to int value. I check in two ways: with JQ and pure JS:

My code:

```
alert('jq: '+$('#element').css('font-size')); // int value

var labelElement = document.getElementById('element');
var fontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(labelElement, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
alert('pureJS: '+fontSize); // int value
```

I take screenshot from Chrome, in developer tools it sees font-size in right value.

### Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]
Anybody knows why it happen?

Thanks so much for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought the issue was that you were searching for `element` instead of `element-7`, which is what is showing under your mouse, and you were confused by Chrome's `element.style` showing of inline CSS information.  It would help if your image matched your code.

Then I tested in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw8VG/) and saw that wasn't the problem.  The problem is that the two ways you're looking at things use computed values.  The user agent converts your font size to an integer, and if you look at the computed values, you're stuck with that.

What the Chrome developer tools was doing was looking directly at what you entered into the DOM, instead of the computed values.  (If you look at that div in the fiddle or your own test, you'll see that the computed value for font-size is not the same as element.style's value.)  So, do the same, and don't look at the computed values:

```
alert(labelElement.style.fontSize);
```

gives you what you want.  You can do it in jQuery, but it's actually uglier - you'd have to get the style attribute and then parse the string - `alert($("element-7").attr("style");` would be the first step, but parsing that to get the font-size would take much more effort.

I haven't found anything in the css or html specs that say a user agent needs to handle floating point pixels.  All the examples I see for [font-size in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) that use pixels use integers.  And I have found a [blog from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) saying that floating point pixels aren't practical.  This would be why you keep getting int values returned as the computed value - float pixels are not part of the standard.

Comment: Thank you so much. But problem not in id name. I have used 'element' name only for example in real project it generated  name and I get tag id this way : '$('#'+child[i].id).attr('id')'

Comment: @abibock_un I've updated my answer.  You should find the updated one much more useful.  :-)